# Converting string to float using QgsExpression()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to convert a string column `Rainfall` of point layer `weather_l` to float:

```
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(weather_l))

num_float = QgsExpression('float(fea["Rainfall"])')

with edit(weather_l):
    for fea in weather_l.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(fea)
        if not fea['Rainfall'].isalpha():
            fea['Rain_D'] = num_float.evaluate(context)
        weather_l.updateFeature(fea)
```

but `num_float.evaluate(context)` returns `None`. How can I correct

```
num_float = QgsExpression('float(fea["Rainfall"])')
```

to convert the string to a float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is mixing Python and Qgis function syntax.

Try the following expression syntax:

```
QgsExpression('to_real("Rainfall")')
```

You need to pass only the field name in double quotes to the `to_real` function.